# How get companion method reference (KFunction<>) by refelection

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reflection, companion-object

In Java it is possible to get a reference to static method in the following way (using *reflection*):

```
Method method = Class.forName("java.util.HashMap").getMethod("put", Object.class, Object.class);
```

In Kotlin it is possible to get a reference (type *KFunctionX<>*) to instance method in the following way  (*using reflection*):

> ```
>     var methodRef : KFunction0<Unit> = someInatance::instanceMethod
> ```

**But** when trying to get a *companion method* (using *reflection*) in the following way:

> ```
>     var companionMethod = SomeJavaClass::someCompanionMethod
> ```

I'm getting an unresolved reference error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) suggest, when you don't provide a name to the companion object (unnamed companion), it gets `Companion` by default.

So the following should work fine:

```kotlin
val companionMethod = SomeKotlinClass.Companion::someCompanionMethod
```

And if you name your companion object, you can reference it with its name:

```kotlin
class SomeKotlinClass {
    companion object Named {
        fun someCompanionMethod() {...}
    }
}

val companionMethod = SomeKotlinClass.Named::someCompanionMethod
```

#### Edit:

As the OP is still confused why `SomeKotlinClass::someCompanionMethod` does not work. Here's the explaination:

You can still reference the companion with `.Companion` when you are calling the functions from it as well, like `SomeKotlinClass.Companion.someCompanionMethod(...)`.

```kotlin
// This works :)
val s = SomeKotlinClass
val companionMethod = s::testFunction

// but this doesn't :(
val companionMethod = SomeKotlinClass::testFunction
```

Well, its because the `::` does not resolve companion.

Why? Because it will be ambiguous if it will, as function of same name can be defined in both companion and class, it won't be able to differentiate between them.

But at call-site compiler can differentiate between member and companion calls, as you call companion as `SomeKotlinClass.testFunction()` and member on its instance: `instanceOfSomeKotlinClass.testFunction()`.

Comment: Thanks. Although,  it is a little bit surprising that when calling the method we don't need the *companion keyword* and when using reflection we need and also the keyword should start with a capital letter ('C')...

Comment: @Eitanos30 added explaination

Comment: Captial-C `Companion` is not a keyword. It's the default name for a companion object when you don't provide a name.

Comment: @Tenfour04, good to know the fact about the *Companion* with the Capitla-C. Thanks

Comment: @Animesh Sahu, i didn't knew that *val s = SomeKotlinClass* is valid. good to know. The additional explantion helped me a lot! I had another mistake when trying to use instance and not the class name. If you set the companion with the name, what would you write instead of  *val s = SomeKotlinClass*?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu, i will hope you will help me. you told that ambiguous situation may occur class will have also a member function with the same name. But when using reflection for static you will write the class name and after that *:: testFunction*, while for a member function you will write the **instance name** and after that *::testFunction*. So it isn't the same. I can't see the ambiguous

Comment: @Eitanos30 But the thing is `SomeClass::memberFunction` is not bound to any object, i.e. you can call it on any object you like `SomeClass::memberFunction(instance, args)`. But if you create a reference like `instance::memberFunction` it is only bounded to that particular instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that you want the companion object:

```
val companionMethod = SomeJavaClass.Companion::someCompanionMethod
```